# Calculating Lebesgue measure (area) of certain set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-measure, area

Fix $b,c \in (0,1)$. How should I go about calculating $\lambda^{2}\{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]: 0\leq cx +(1-c)y\leq b \}$, where $\lambda^{2}$ denotes the 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

I'm pretty sure this should be doable using elementary calculus, but I can't get it.

Hints are preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculus is overkill: this is just geometry.

Since $0 < c < 1$, $cx + (1-c) y \ge 0$ for all $(x,y)$ in the square.
$cx + (1-c) y = b$, on the other hand, is a straight line that does pass through the square. 
Figure out where it intersects the boundary of the square (the details will
depend on how $b$ relates to $c$ and $1-c$).  Your region is either a triangle,
the complement of a triangle, or a trapezoid.